# DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types entity y c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, linq

Tengo un problema para poder realizar una query de entity, la cual le agregue una condicion de tipo contains para buscar los registros especificos que ingreso a traves de un textbox multiline y que separo mediante coma a traves de un método que me regresa una cadena, esto con el fin de poder buscarlos, pero me genera un error en la query que no he podido resolver

> System.ArgumentException: 'DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types.'

```html
public List<CambioEstatus> QueryResultados()
    {
        string situacion;
        if (RadCmbAccion.SelectedValue == "1")
        {
            situacion = "4";
        }
        else
        {
            situacion = "3";
        }
        string valoresCtas = regresa_info();

        CatalogoContainer entidad = new CatalogoContainer();
        List<CambioEstatus> query = (from c in entidad.CUENTA
                                     join ct in entidad.CUENTA_TIPO
                                     on c.id_CUENTA_TIPO equals ct.id_CUENTA_TIPO
                                     join ffp in entidad.FACTURA_FORMA_PAGO
                                     on c.id_FORMA_PAGO equals ffp.id_FORMA_PAGO
                                     join cs in entidad.CUENTA_SITUACION
                                     on c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION equals cs.id_CUENTA_SITUACION
                                     where c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION.Equals(situacion) && valoresCtas.Contains(Convert.ToString(c.id_CUENTA))
                                     select new CambioEstatus()
                                     {
                                         IDCUENTA=c.id_CUENTA.ToString()
                                     }).ToList();
                                     
      return query;
    }
```

en este metodo separo la informacion a traves de coma

```html
public string regresa_info()
    {
        string todos = "";
        string todos_1 = "";
        string[] ar = RadTxtBuscar.Text.Split('\n');
        int g = ar.Length;
        string valor = "";

        int cont = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
        {
            cont++;
            if (cont == g)
            {
                valor = ar[i].ToString().Replace('\r', ' ').Trim();
                todos_1 = "'" + valor + "'";
            }
            else
            {
                valor = ar[i].ToString().Replace('\r', ' ').Trim();
                todos_1 = "'" + valor + "',";
            }

            todos += "" + todos_1 + "";

        }
        return todos;
    }
```

esta clase son las propiedades para poder crear la lista generica

```html
public class CambioEstatus
{
    public string IDCUENTA { get; set; }
    public string RFC { get; set; }
    public string RAZONSOCIAL { get; set; }
    public string TIPO { get; set; }
    public string FORMAPAGO { get; set; }
    public string ESTATUS { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema esta en la traducción que intenta realizar Entity Framework  al convertir los tipos, ya que esto no puede ser transformado a SQL, por lo que deberías de intentar con esto:

```
List<CambioEstatus> query = (from c in entidad.CUENTA
                join ct in entidad.CUENTA_TIPO
                    on c.id_CUENTA_TIPO equals ct.id_CUENTA_TIPO
                join ffp in entidad.FACTURA_FORMA_PAGO
                    on c.id_FORMA_PAGO equals ffp.id_FORMA_PAGO
                join cs in entidad.CUENTA_SITUACION
                    on c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION equals cs.id_CUENTA_SITUACION
                where c.id_CUENTA_SITUACION.Equals(situacion)
                select new CambioEstatus()
                {
                    IDCUENTA=c.id_CUENTA.ToString()
                }).ToList();

query = query.Where(c=>valoresCtas.Contains(Convert.ToString(c.id_CUENTA))).ToList();
```

Comment: coloque como indicas, pero me sigue generando el mismo error

Comment: ya vi mi error esta en la primera condición del where ya que el campo id_cuenta_situacion en BD es de tipo byte y la variable situación es de tipo string, entonces por eso no se podían comparar,  gracias por tu respuesta de todos modos me sirvio mucho